# Add a border to a ListView item (only around the image)

Tags: c#, winforms

I have found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693837/how-to-add-border-to-items-in-a-listview-control-using-c) which offers this solution on how to add a border to a ListView item:

[image]

But I only want to add the border around the image, something like this:

[image]

Can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the `LargeIcon` `View` mode, the images are drawn **centered** and their `Size` is in the related `LargeImageList.ImageSize` so something like this should work:

```
private void listView1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.DrawDefault = true;
    Size sz = listView1.LargeImageList.ImageSize;
    int w = sz.Width + 4;
    int h = sz.Height + 3;
    int x = (e.Bounds.Width - sz.Width) / 2 + e.Bounds.X - 2;
    int y = e.Bounds.Top + 1 ;
    using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2f))
    {
        pen.Alignment = PenAlignment.Center;
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, x, y, w, h);
    }     
}
```

Here is my `ListView`:

[image]

Of course, if you want the frame to go over the full width (`e.Bounds.Width`) you can simply restrict only the height as shown..:

```
private void listView1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
  e.DrawDefault = true;
  Size sz = listView1.LargeImageList.ImageSize;
  e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, e.Bounds.X,e.Bounds.Y, e.Bounds.Width,sz.Height + 2);
}
```

[image]

If you want to make the currently focussed item stand out you can do something like this:

```
Color bCol = e.State.HasFlag(ListViewItemStates.Focused) ?
    Color.LightBlue : listView1.BackColor;
using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(bCol))
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y, e.Bounds.Width, sz.Height + 2);
```

before drawing the Rectangle:

[image]

Or you could pick the color of the rectangle according to the item state..

Comment: Hi. I have tried your code and I have a question: is there a way to also highlight the border when selecting an item, because when I select an item, only the image and the text gets selected without the border.

Comment: Yes,, you could add something like this before drawing the rectangle: `if (e.State.HasFlag(ListViewItemStates.Selected) )    e.Graphics.FillRectangle( Brushes.AliceBlue, e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y, e.Bounds.Width, sz.Height + 2);` (Pick your color!) Or you could use the same check and draw the Rectangle in a different Color than Red..

Comment: See my updated answer..!