# How can I insert a line separator between two rows in a Winform c# ListView?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

Is it possible to insert programmatically a line separator between two rows in a Winform c# ListView ?

Like that for example :

[image]

Comment: Probable duplicate of [How to add border to items in a listview control using C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693837/how-to-add-border-to-items-in-a-listview-control-using-c#32694195)

Comment: It's actually a good lead I think but I did not succeed to do it with... Is there a expert who can find a solution from it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going off of the answer provided in the comments above.  You need to hook into the `DrawItem` event and draw the line at the bottom after whatever item you want is drawn.  Here I've drawn a line after item with `Text == "2"` is drawn:

```
private void ListView1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.DrawDefault = true;

    if (e.Item.Text == "2")
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, e.Bounds.Left, e.Bounds.Bottom, e.Bounds.Right, e.Bounds.Bottom);
    }
}
```

You may need to draw the line underneath multiple items if more than one item is placed on a row in your `ListView`.

[image]

Comment: I did finally find the same yesterday evening and wanted to put it here but you did it ! :) thanks.

Comment: (forgot to say that I used the Tag to mark elements with the line ;) )

Comment: You're welcome and good use of the `Tag` property - it often comes in handy.